# How to tell Angular 2 how to find my Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

In my Angular 2 development environment all of my JavaScript files are located with reference to "/".  When I go into my production environment they are in "/ui".  So, to make it work I have to manually change the script tags to point to "/ui/bundle.js".   How do I tell Angular 2 to look in a different place in Production?

Comment: Do you have a dev/prod config?

Comment: Yes, I am using webpack and I have a config for dev and one for prod.